# Hardware interrupt between Raspberry pi and Atmega 328

Tags: raspberry-pi, atmega

I have connected my RPI and atmega328 together in order to control the start of an event on my arduino. In order to do so, GPIO 25 (RPI) is connected directly to pin7 (Arduino PD7). I've got a python script on the RPI witch set the GPIO 25 to high then back to LOW:

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(25, 1)
    #Do some stuff
    GPIO.output(25, 0)
```

The arduino is waiting in a loop for either a physical button to be pressed or the pin7 to be set to HIGH by the RPI:

```
const int interrupt = 7;
const int button = 13;
const int led = 9;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(interrupt, INPUT);
  pinMode(button,INPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  bool on = false;
  bool buttonOn = false;

  while (!on || !buttonOn) {
    on = digitalRead(interrupt);
    buttonOn = digitalRead(button);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Now unfortunately this doesn't work. I have checked the logic level of the atmega328 (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels) and it seems that 3.3V is good enough for HIGH signal.

Am I missing something with the pull up /pull down resistance? I know the PD7 on the atmega is specified as follow:

> Port D is an 8-bit bi-directional I/O port with internal pull-up
>   resistors (selected for each bit). The Port D output buffers have
>   symmetrical drive characteristics with both high sink and source
>   capability. As inputs, Port D pins that are externally pulled low will
>   source current if the pull-up resistors are activated. The Port D pins
>   are tristated when a reset condition becomes active, even if the clock
>   is not running.

EDIT:
I have done more testing and I am getting the HIGH or LOW value correctly. It seems that the issue comes from the:

`while ((!on) || (!buttonOn)) {`

Is there an issue with Arduino and the OR operator in a while loop? Even when one condition is true and the other one is false, it never goes out of the loop.

Comment: 1. I'd never use a 3.3v system with a 5v system directly. Always use a level shifter or some kind of buffer. 2. buttonOn = digitalRead(interupt); -> buttonOn = digitalRead(button); 3. Have you used a multimeter to check the voltage on the input pin?

Comment: I assumed it is safe to do it from 3.3V to 5V, I always use a level converter for 5V to 3.3V. Yes I have check with the multimeter and I've around 3.3V on the input pin of the ATmega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ((!on) || (!buttonOn)) {
}
```

That loop will run as long as one of the variables is false.
Yesterday I was for some reason thinking that you were reading the interrupt pin twice when reading your code.

Comment: Thank you, I should have used && operator. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

3.3 v output should be ok to turn the Arduino input high.

You can have a wiring problem or your raspberry pi can be so fast that the arduino misses the pulse.

Change your program on the raspberry pi to leave the output high for so long (e.g. 10) seconds that you can measure it with a multimeter to see that you are setting the right pin.

Does the Arduino now see the input?

Comment: I should have precised it but the "#do stuff" part last more than 20 seconds. With the multimeter I have 3.29V on the RPI pin and the same on pin 7 of the ATmega.

Comment: Hmm. Could it be that you have the wire connected to a wrong pin on the arduino? Does the arduino see the pin always low or always high?

Comment: It is definitely the correct pin, I have checked multiple times. The arduino never get out of the loop " while (!on || !buttonOn)" so it remains at LOW even with a verified 3.29V on the pin 7...

Comment: 2 suggestions: 1) remove the dual reading of pin 7 from your loop, just for fun it and see if it does anything. 2) If that does nothing, take a trimmer potentiometer, with a value of something like 1K to 10KOhm. Disconnect the rpi from the arduino. Attach one end of the trimpot to the arduino +5v and the other end to ground. Connect the middle of the trimpot to pin 7 AND your multimeter. Now adjust the voltage in pin 7 between 0.5...4.5v and see if your code triggers. If not, there is a problem with the code or the atmega. Don't adjust the trimpot closer than 10% to either end to avoid damage.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have done some test this morning and it seems to get the HIGH and LOW level as expected. It seems that the issue comes from the while loop and the OR operator.